# Local variable importance vs Global Variable Importance

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Is there any technique to find local variable important? For example in credit card concept, is there any way to specify why a person is not eligible for a credit card? or which features cause this person to not be eligible to get a credit card? I have never heard about local variable importance so any resource would be appreciated.

Comment: Local variable importance is a feature of random forests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try LIME (Locally Interpretable Model Agnostic Explainations)
They give you the explanation for local variables.

I would suggest you look at two libraries in Python.
[Eli5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) for local explanations.

Comment: Welcome to CV! The aim of CV is to have standalone solutions to questions, unreliant on external links. A good answer will provide background and at least a brief explanation of concepts. Links to more in depth resources are welcome but should be provided a good context and the answer should still be informative in the event of link rot.